# Addin Property To a user_created Component

Tags: c#, user-controls

I've written a windows form control library. I've used it at my main desktop (form) application. But I can not see the properties I have added my control library !

The way to add property to a user_created component is possible with working on class view.
But I can not make my properties shown in properties windows like other default controls (e.g Button)

Is there any solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any public property should appear in the propety designer, e.g.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Number Format
    /// </summary>
    [Category("Formatting"), DefaultValue("#,##0"), Description("Formatting string for numbers")]
    public string NumberFormat { get; set; }
```

The attributes set how it is displayed in the property grid and are all part of the System.ComponentModel namespace

Comment: @najmeddine : it is not important if the property public or not 
[if I'm wrong please correct]

@ JDunkerley : I thank you lot, it works!

Comment: I tested that, it does not work with private or protected properties (C# .NET 2.0). If you succeeded, can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: I'd tested it too, you're right private or protected properties (.net 2.0 or 3.5) are not shown. Thanks for test. My property was public.